# Can someone help me with the hover tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this line of code hover but it doesn’t hovers at the spot that I want it to hover. It hovers at the same line. Here’s the code for html and css that I have.  
css:

```css
.whitebox:hover{
  background: #a60505;
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebox"> 
  <h2> <a href="partsofdw.html" <br>
   Different <br>
   Parts of the <br>
   Internet </a></h2>
</div>
```

Instead of only executing the command for the div, when I hover over the same line it executes the code and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you show us your `whitebox` properties?

Comment: Do clue what you mean.

Comment: @epascarello I think he wants to change the background of `whitebox` when hovering over it, but it already changes the background-color when hovers the part which is next to his div on the right. So I guess it's some sort of wrong width-property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the OP, discovered the missing div tag because of faulty formatting.

I also discovered, by using the snippet, that there is a `>` missing in the `a` tag. Could be part the problem.

The main issue is that you shouldn't assign the size values on `:hover`, but on the class itself. See CSS code below.

However, I would suggest to use `display: inline-block` - to adjust the `.whitebox` element to its content - instead of using `height` and `width`, and also adjust the margin of your `h2` to better control the spacing.

Note: I also removed the first `<br/>`.

```css
.whitebox {
   display: inline-block;
   /*
   width: 150px;
   height: 110px;
   */
}

.whitebox:hover {
  background: #a60505;
}

.whitebox > h2 {
  margin: 1rem; /* the font size of your body */
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebox"> 
  <h2> <a href="partsofdw.html"> <!-- <br> -->
   Different <br>
   Parts of the <br>
   Internet </a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer and if this doesn't work then please share your full code:

```css
CSS:

  .whitebox:hover{
    background: #a60505;
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

```html
HTML:
    <div class="whitebox">
       <h2> <a href="partsofdw.html" <br>
       Different <br>
       Parts of the <br>
       Internet </a></h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To hover the containt:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   h2:hover{
    background: #a60505;
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <h2>
       <a href="partsofdw.html"><br>
       Different <br>
       Parts of the <br>
       Internet 
       </a>
      </h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` code needs to be edited. Cause you don't have any `whitebox` class and it has some syntax errors! Ihave fixed that for you!

```css
.whitebox:hover{
  background: #a60505;
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebox">
  <h2> 
    <a href="partsofdw.html">
      Different <br>
      Parts of the <br>
      Internet 
     </a>
  </h2>
</div>
```